# How does noise input size affect fake image generation with GANs?

Tags: neural-networks, generative-adversarial-networks, hyper-parameters, deepfakes

In Generative Adversarial Networks, the Generator takes noise vector as input and feeds it forward to create an image. The noise vector consists of random numbers sampled from the normal distribution. In several examples that I've encountered, the noise vector had 100 numbers ([implementation  1](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan), [implementation 2](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/Keras-GAN/blob/master/dcgan/dcgan.py)). Is there a reason this number is used? How does noise size affect the generation image?